# (mimic-iii) Why D_LABITEMS doesn't have reference range while D_ITEMs has?

Tags: mimic-iii

Often Lab test should come with a reference range, which is likely to be included in D_LABITEMS. 
On the other hand, although D_ITEMS has columns lownormalvalue and highnormalvalue, there is no record that has a no-null value of these two columns. 
Is this caused by a mistake when exporting?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally the D_ITEMS and D_LABITEMS tables would include reference ranges, but this data was not made available to the MIT Laboratory for Computational Physiology. As a result, it was not possible to include the reference ranges in the MIMIC-III dataset.

The current version of MIMIC-III does not include lownormalvalue and highnormalvalue columns, so it appears that you are using an early release of the dataset. I would suggest updating to the [latest version](http://mimic.physionet.org/about/releasenotes/), which includes bug fixes and additional data.

If reference ranges become available in the future, then the data will be added.